# Drop method of jquery droppable is not triggered for rows dragged out of table zone

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've come across a very strange behaviour of my table with draggable rows. Everything seems to work fine with the only exception when I try to drag a row far below my table area and drop. It is actually dropped on the right place as the last row of the table, but drop method does not fire for some reason !
Any ideas how to solve this ?

http://jsfiddle.net/4fdohs4r/

```
$("tbody").sortable({
    items: "> tr",
    appendTo: "parent",
    helper: "clone"
}).disableSelection();

$(".table tr").droppable({
    hoverClass: "drophover",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    drop: function(e, ui) {
        $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
        alert('I work only if I am dropped gently within table area')
    }
});
```

Comment: did you try to limit the drop area?

Comment: No, I don't know how to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can limit your drop area with the

```
containment: '#somecontainer',
```

option. See also here: [containment](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement)